# Get number of rows updated by Laravel DB Transaction

Tags: php, database, laravel-4, transactions

I carry out DB transaction like this:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try
{
    foreach ($updates as $column_name => $new_value) {
        DB::table('my_table')
            ->where('id', '=', $line_id)
            ->update(array($column_name => $new_value));
    }
    DB::commit();
    return Response::make('Updated', 200);
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    DB::rollback();
    return Response::make('Error - '. $ex->getMessage(), 500);
}
```

Is it possible to get the number of rows affected/updated when I carry out the `DB::commit();` and return it in my response?

**EDIT**

The `$updates` contains `key` = `value` array (where the `key` is the column name).

If an update like this occurs: `UPDATE some_table SET some_number = some_number WHERE id = 1` the resulting affected row count will be `0` (i.e. nothing really changed).

However, if an update like this occurs: `UPDATE some_table SET some_number = some_number + 1 WHERE id = 1` for example, then this will result in affected row count of `1`.

This is what I am trying to determine in my code, once the transaction is committed, has any values been really updated.

Answer (score 0):

### NEW

You could update only if the value is different from the past one:

```
$count = DB::table('my_table')
  ->where('id', '=', $line_id)
  ->where($column_name, '!=', $new_value)
  ->count();
```

In this way you can say if the given row has a different value and if you are going to change it.

### OLD

A `count` before the query:

```
$number = DB::table('my_table')
  ->where('id', '=', $line_id)
  ->count();
```

Return in the response:

```
return Response::make('Updated ' . $number, 200);
```

Comment: I am trying to determine if any rows were updated, when the transaction is committed - not count the number of rows in a table. My update query does a dynamic update on the table, i.e. any column on the table could have been updated.

Comment: My question updated with better explanation of what I am after.

Comment: I think that you're trying to obtain the value of [ROW_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count).

Comment: I think that if you try to update a row with the same column value of before, the query will be executed and you can't say if the past value was the same.